# Construct dataframe from dict and relabel the columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to construct a dataframe from dictionary + relabel the columns, but I am getting a blank dataframe. Please advise what I am doing wrong:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],
              'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21],
              'University' : ['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU', 'BHU']},
columns = list('ABC'))
```

Comment: remove `columns = list('ABC')` part

Comment: @AnuragDabas but I want to keep it or rename it, can I do it on the fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the column names twice. Once as the dictionary keys, and once with the `columns` parameter, which conflicts. If you want to rename your columns ['A', 'B', 'C'], do it after:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],
                   'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21],
                   'University' : ['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU', 'BHU']},
                 )
df.columns = list('ABC')
```

output:

```
           A   B    C
0      Ankit  23  BHU
1  Aishwarya  21  JNU
2    Shaurya  22   DU
3   Shivangi  21  BHU
```

Most efficient would be to do directly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],
                   'B' : [23, 21, 22, 21],
                   'C' : ['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU', 'BHU']},
                 )
```

If you really need to input the dictionary as it is, another option is:

```
my_dict = {'Name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],
           'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21],
           'University' : ['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU', 'BHU']}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict).rename(columns=dict(zip(my_dict, list('ABC'))))
```

Comment: too fast i am about to post this `dict(zip(my_dict, list('ABC')`

Answer (score 3):

You can try storing your dict in a variable and make a dataframe out of the values of dict because if you use dictionary by default the keys of dictionary is act as the column name:

```
d={'Name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],
              'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21],
              'University' : ['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU', 'BHU']}
#Finally:
df=pd.DataFrame(d.values(),index=list('ABC')).T
```

OR

you can rename your columns after making a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['Ankit', 'Aishwarya', 'Shaurya', 'Shivangi'],
          'Age' : [23, 21, 22, 21],
          'University' : ['BHU', 'JNU', 'DU', 'BHU']})
df.columns=list('ABC')
```